# Swiss Alps visit around early November

Tags: trains, automobiles, switzerland

I will be visiting Switzerland on early November and I'm still planning the trip.

I never drove on snow before, so I don't know if it would be hard to drive around some regions like the Swiss Alps. I'm thinking primarily Zermatt, Lugano and Verbier but I'm opened to suggestion.

Since driving around Switzerland is something new to me, I thought it would be easier to appreciate the scenery if I first travel by train around the Swiss Alps and then I could rent a car and visit whatever I like+plan next.

How snowy is Switzerland on November? Will I get a better trip (in terms of peace of mind and other travel related troubles) if I move around by train instead of by car?

Comment: In November it snows rarely, and if it does, it won't stick on roads for a long time. As gerrit said, Zermatt and Verbier are car-free anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will I get a better trip (in terms of peace of mind and other travel related troubles) if I move around by train instead of by car?

**Yes.**

You seek to visit Zermatt, Lugano, and Verbier.

Zermatt and Verbier are car-free.  Switzerland has excellent (if expensive) public transportation.  In most areas, you do not need a car.

If you want to explore the area around Lugano you might rent a car, as certainly it adds flexibility, but then I would recommend only renting a car in Lugano and returning it there, while keeping the rest by train.  Lugano is much warmer than Zermatt and Verbier anyway, so you will likely not have to drive on snow unless you go high up into the mountains.

Comment: Thanks! That was the kind of answer I was looking for. I found many "don't visit Switzerland in November because..." but if I can easily move around by train, I will be very happy!